# No mouse pointer settings/unable to reduce mouse pointer speed - Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: mouse, logitech

[My touchpad is working perfectly but when i connect my wireless mouse cursor moves so fast but there are no settings for it to reduce.
Device: HP Pavilion
Model: 15-au175tx
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2(Latest)
Mouse brand: Logitech](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkQW3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using a Logitech mouse and unifying receiver (has an orange star on it)...

If you dual-boot with Windows, boot into Windows and use the Logitech mouse and unifying software to set the desired mouse characteristics you desire, like speed. Booting back into Ubuntu will remember those settings.

If you **don't** dual-boot with Windows, take the mouse and the unifying received to another computer that is running Windows, install the Logitech mouse and unifying software, and set it up there. When you return these items to your computer, it will remember those settings.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
xinput --list --short
```

output:

```
abcd@abcd-abcde:~$ xinput --list --short

Virtual core pointer

↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

↳ Logitech USB RECEIVER                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

My pointing devices are a `Logitech USB RECEIVER` and a `Synaptics TouchPad`.

To list out device properties:

```
xinput --list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
```

**Another option:** `xinput --list-props 11` as `11` is the number that is shown above in its parent property (SynPS/2 Synaptic TouchPad).

Now reduce it's property values to suit your need:

```
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (267):   2.500000
```

using this command

```
xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5
```